# I have a folder full of pdfs I am wanting to create a code that spits out a list of all pdfs that contain the color blue

Tags: python, pdf

Like the title says, a bunch of pdfs that need to be gone through and a list made showing the pdfs that have the color blue in them.

I tried using a snippet of code from another post that is similar to try and get a list of colors from one document thinking if I could create a loop to go through all documents and export the output to excel and filter for a specific color, that might work, but I cant even get it to work for a single pdf:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- Encoding: UTF-8 -*-

import minecart

colors = set()

with open("F://Prints/0-25162.PDF", "rb") as file:
    document = minecart.Document(file)
    page = document.get_page(1)
    for shape in page.shapes:
        if shape.outline:
            colors.add(shape.outline.color.as_rgb())

for color in colors: print (color)
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use the built-in `glob.glob('*.pdf')` to get all the pdfs in a dir. then you can iterate over them and check if blue is in there

Answer (score 0):

I would try to render the PDF into PNG or similar bitmap format, then load it as a Python pixel array (using Pillow or similar), and look for blue pixels. Not sure which library you'd use for the rasterizing, but Pillow or pdf2image might do the job. Alternatively, you can do it with ImageMagick prior to the Python processing.

Comment: Alright, I just exported a bunch of PDF as PNGs.  It is very time consuming.  I have about 1900 pdfs to convert.  I am using pyautogui to open them from file explorer and export from a pdf editing software.  I have a feeling this is not the best way...

Comment: If you have that many files, don't do it manually. Use Python's file system functionality (os & pathlib) to find the files. Then convert them inside your script.